# How to get a list of all Android widgets in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I am making a flutter launcher for android. I would like users to be able to add their widgets from the applications that they have installed. But I can't seem to find a solution how to do this. I found information that this is done using the [AppWidgetProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider), but I do not know how to apply it in flutter. I also found such a [home_widget](https://pub.dev/packages/home_widget) library, but this is used to create my own widget. Maybe someone came across this question? Thanks.